# Some reputation of the upvoted wiki post (Q&A) should be awarded to the original author

Tags: feature-request, reputation, voting, community-wiki, up-votes

An upvoted question or answer earns +10. But if the author has decided to make it a wiki for betterment of the post or has been made wiki by the community moderators, then reputation per upvote is straight 0! This is a drastic difference.
There are several wiki posts where the original author has edited more revisions.

**Proposal**: The original author should be awarded +1 or +2 or whatever is deemed appropriate for every upvote on wiki answer.
As a good side effect, this will also help the author to know any voting activity on that post.
<sub>Don't have any specific suggestion for downvotes.</sub>

Comment: No, this isn't a drastic difference in my opinion. By making a post community wiki, you allow other people with <2k rep to edit it, adding more information which couldn't have been done otherwise, since it would deviate from the author's intent. Therefore, if many people had put effort to edit and improve a CW post, it'd have been unfair to give the rep of the upvotes to the OP - OP still earns the reputation from bounty.

Comment: @double, to encourage other people to edit & contribute to a post, someone at least has to create a reasonably good post. For that effort, the author certainly deserves some **royalty**. When author wiki-fy the post, that itself shows their carefree attitude towards reputation. Let the system do it's bit by small appreciation.

Comment: IIRC this was one of the most controversial aspects of the late Documentation project - one could make a minor improvement and then earn a small amount of rep for every subsequent upvote. A few early enhancements to highly popular items could net you upwards of 1k.

Comment: Most people creating CWs don't put much effort in the original answer and they expect other people to improve it by CWing it. OPs are rewarded by getting bounties as I mentioned above. See also https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/19/the-future-of-community-wiki/, [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741)

Comment: @Robert, this question is not about reputation award to editors, but the original author. I am not much aware & never did contribute to that documentation project.

Comment: @iammilind What about a small gain of reputation at the point of making a post _community wiki_ (+1 would be fair IMO) once? For the DV conditions this could be still protected.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that this would not be a good change.

When you post a normal answer, you put some effort into it. Thus, it is against the rules to make an edit that would deviate from the original intent of the post author. The more effort you've put, the more the upvotes you will eventually get. And that's fair because YOU are the *author* of the post and the one responsible for its content.

Posting a Community Wiki answer is done more to help future visitors (as a trusted reference) rather than the post owner. This enables
<2k people to edit the post to add more information. Drastic changes are also allowed, as long as they do not deface the post.

To sum up, a CW answer is managed by over one community members and it would be unfair if the original creator got the reputation points from the upvotes in my opinion.

Related posts:

- https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/19/the-future-of-community-wiki
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741

Comment: Not always true. I have made community wikis to preserve an answer given as a comment where the person leaving the comment doesn't want to turn it into an answer themselves (or I leave a note saying for them to leave a comment if they want to post it later as an answer and I will delete wiki). I agree, however, that rep shouldn't be earnt on wikis.

Comment: "No one can make an edit to it to add more information" that's not true. I've had people edit my Answers to add and remove whole sections. Some of that was approved by reviewers and I had one edit completely change what my Answer was. Also, with +2k rep, edits don't even go through review, so only someone going through the history would know the difference.

Comment: @computercarguy well, that's wrong. If people disagree with your answers they should comment. If they want to add to your answer they should answer the question.

Comment: @double-beep-ReinstateMonica, well, some people don't follow the rules, while others decided to make changes I didn't want to make that would have changed the intent of my Answer, including specific words I used. The one I can remember that completely changed my Answer was reverted by a reviewer and the editor scolded for making such a vast change while also told to make their own Answer. I've lived long enough to know there's a difference between "should" and "is".

Comment: Then, what if when a user _edits_ a community wiki, a bit of the reputation from any subsequent upvotes from the next some amount of time get awarded to the _editor_?